# Another way to split datatable in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
 tbl.Columns.Add("Column");
 for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++)
  tbl.Rows.Add(i.ToString());


                 DataTable[] splittedtables = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 12)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
                    .ToArray();

                DataTable dtarr1 = splittedtables[0];
```

- This is my code, It is working fine, but I want the most efficient way.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: If you want a code review  (including optimization of working code) try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Comments  you want to convert List to DataTable:

Here is the Common method which i am using

**ConvertToDataTable**

```
 public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {

        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, null, null);
    }

public class ObjectShredder<T>
{
    private FieldInfo[] _fi;
    private PropertyInfo[] _pi;
    private Dictionary<string, int> _ordinalMap;
    private Type _type;

    public ObjectShredder()
    {
        _type = typeof(T);
        _fi = _type.GetFields();
        _pi = _type.GetProperties();
        _ordinalMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public DataTable Shred(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
        {
            return ShredPrimitive(source, table, options);
        }


        if (table == null)
        {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        // now see if need to extend datatable base on the type T + build ordinal map
        table = ExtendTable(table, typeof(T));

        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (options != null)
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), (LoadOption)options);
                }
                else
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable ShredPrimitive(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options)
    {
        if (table == null)
        {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        if (!table.Columns.Contains("Value"))
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));
        }

        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                values[table.Columns["Value"].Ordinal] = e.Current;

                if (options != null)
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, (LoadOption)options);
                }
                else
                {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable ExtendTable(DataTable table, Type type)
    {
        // value is type derived from T, may need to extend table.
        foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields())
        {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name))
            {
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(f.Name) ? table.Columns[f.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(f.Name);
                _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name))
            {
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(p.Name);
                _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }

    public object[] ShredObject(DataTable table, T instance)
    {

        FieldInfo[] fi = _fi;
        PropertyInfo[] pi = _pi;

        if (instance.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            ExtendTable(table, instance.GetType());
            fi = instance.GetType().GetFields();
            pi = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
        }

        Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            values[_ordinalMap[f.Name]] = f.GetValue(instance);
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
        {
            values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null);
        }
        return values;
    }





}
```

Comment: What exactly you need then?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static DataTable create_DataTable_From_Generic_Class(Type t)
    {
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        FieldInfo[] fI = t.GetFields();
        for(int i = 0; i < fI.Length; i++)
        {
            DataColumn dC = new DataColumn(fI[i].Name, fI[i].FieldType);
            d.Columns.Add(dC);
        }
        return d;
    }
    public static object[] Create_Datatable_Row_From_Generic_Class(Type t, object instance,DataTable dt)
    {

        FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
        object[] ret = new object[f.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = t.GetField(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName).GetValue(instance);

        }
        return ret;

    }
```

This is for fields. Repeat for properties and whatever other types you want converted.